# Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'., L tried all the hacks l know nothing helped

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

l even have the imports in the appmodule.ts but this can not fix auth l tried the answered once but no helped. so can anyone help me

```
     import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
    import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
    })
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
      mobile = '';
      password = '';

      constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {}

      ngOnInit() {}

      async login() {
        const { mobile, password } = this;
        try {
            const res = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            mobile + '@saveme.com',
            password
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.dir(err)
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of @angular/fire are you using in the project?
from version 6.0.0 they dropped the auth property and should use `this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` otherwise you can downgrade the package version to 5.4.2

Comment: okay l was using version 6 let me try both solutions

Answer (score 0):

You may have tried to access the `firebase.auth.Auth` interface directly. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth):

> Do not call this constructor directly. Instead, use [`firebase.auth()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth).

So try the following

```js
const res = await this.afAuth.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword();
```

Comment: l tried it as well but still giving me the same error

Comment: and another thing the option I'm getting is authState when it tries to auto-complete but doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

For AngularFireAuth, you should import AngularFireAuthModule at your rootmodule

```
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,        // <------ mention here
  ]
})
```

Comment: l have the imports also in my root module, that's why I'm stuck all these possible hacks failed